# Proof of 3.461.5 of Gradshteyn Book needed

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, integration

The 3.461.5 Equation of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik book is as given below $$\int_u^{\infty}e^{-\mu x^2}x^{-2}\, dx=\frac{1}{u}e^{-\mu u^2}-\sqrt{\mu \pi}\left[1-\Phi(\sqrt{\mu u})\right]$$ where $\Phi(x)$ is defined as $$\Phi(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$ I want to know how to proof this equation? Any hint or reference for this will be very helpful. I will be very thankful to you for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint differentiate both sides w.r.t to $\mu$

Comment: Looks awfully similar to a Integration By Parts. That  $\Phi(x)$ is actually known as the Error function, $erf(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $u$ in the denominator of the first term?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes its $u$

Comment: The current (8th) edition of G&S (edited by Daniel Zwilinger) has a note ${}^{11}$ on this formula, which means it was corrected for the 7th edition.  Perhaps that was when they moved the $u$ outside the radical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v = e^{-\mu x^2}$ and $dw = dx/x^2$.  Then integrating by parts we have
\begin{align}
\int_u^\infty e^{-\mu x^2} \frac{dx}{x^2} &= \left[ e^{-\mu x^2} \left( - \frac{1}{x} \right) \right]_u^\infty - \int_u^\infty \left( - \frac{1}{x} \right) \left( - 2 \mu x e^{-\mu x^2} dx \right) \\
&= \left[ 0 - \left( -\frac{1}{u} e^{-\mu u^2} \right) \right] - 2 \mu \int_u^\infty e^{-\mu x^2} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{u} e^{-\mu u^2} - 2 \mu \int_{\sqrt{\mu} u}^\infty e^{-t^2} \left( \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\mu}} \right) & (t \equiv \sqrt{\mu} x) \\
&= \frac{1}{u} e^{-\mu u^2} - 2 \sqrt{\mu} \left[ \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} dt - \int_0^{\sqrt{\mu} u} e^{-t^2} dt \right]
\end{align}
The first integral that remains is well-known to be equal to $\sqrt{\pi}/2$, and the second one is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi} \Phi(\sqrt{\mu} u)$.  Plugging these in, we achieve the desired result.

(Note that the argument of $\Phi$ in the integral should be $\sqrt{\mu} u$, rather than $\sqrt{\mu u}$.  I assume this was a typo you made in entering the equation—it's also one I made a few times while typing this up.)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I do not know I just wrote it as its written on that book therefore I am not sure if there is typo in that book also. Nevertheless I got the idea how to get there

Comment: @FrankMoses Why not order $\sqrt\mu u$ as $u\sqrt\mu$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I think this will not make any difference in the answer

Comment: @FrankMoses I know, right? But it is clearer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Agreed completely.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I(\mu) &= \int\limits_{u}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}} \int\limits_{u\sqrt{\mu}}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\mu}} \mathrm{erfc}(u\sqrt{\mu}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\mu}} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\mu}}\mathrm{erf}(u\sqrt{\mu})
\end{align}
We let $y^{2} = \mu x^{2}$.

Integrating with respect to $\mu$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{u}^{\infty} \int \mathrm{e}^{-\mu x^{2}} \mathrm{d}\mu \mathrm{d}x
= -\int\limits_{u}^{\infty} x^{-2} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x
\tag{1}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}} \mathrm{d}\mu - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}}\mathrm{erf}(u\sqrt{\mu}) \mathrm{d}\mu
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} I_{1} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} I_{2}
\tag{2}
\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{1} = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}} \mathrm{d}\mu = 2\sqrt{\mu}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
I_{2} &= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}} \mathrm{erf}(u\sqrt{\mu}) \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \frac{2}{u} \int \mathrm{erf}(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{2}{u} x\, \mathrm{erf}(x) + \frac{2}{u} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} \\
&= 2\sqrt{\mu} \mathrm{erf}(u\sqrt{\mu}) + \frac{2}{u} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu u^{2}}
\end{align}
We let $x=u\sqrt{\mu}$.

Inserting $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ into equation \eqref{eq:2}, equating the result with equation \eqref{eq:1}, and simplifying, we have

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{u}^{\infty} x^{-2} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x &= 
\frac{1}{u} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu u^{2}} - \sqrt{\pi \mu} [1 - \mathrm{erf}(u\sqrt{\mu})] \\
&= \frac{1}{u} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu u^{2}} - \sqrt{\pi \mu} \mathrm{erfc}(u\sqrt{\mu})
\end{align}